# How Bitmap is loaded and optimized

Tags: asp.net-core, bitmap

I used the Bitmap package to generate a custom verification code, how can I make the image it generates bigger and clearer. How is this done? Thanks for your help again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q94QD.png)

I goole some answers and none seem to have good results

[optimizing bitmap loading by using aSyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401919/optimizing-bitmap-loading-by-using-asynctask)

Comment: You know those things are made fuzzy intentionally, to foil bots, right?  You should show us the code that creates this if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, modify the picture to JPEG format, it can reduce the size of the picture and it is relatively clear.

```
    static void ImgTestTwo()
        {
            string filename = @"E:\CoreWork\backone.jpg";
            string targetname = @"E:\CoreWork\temp1.jpg";


    
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename);
        //Keep the ratio of the image unchanged, zoom the image
        int width = 1000,
            height = 1000;
        if (bitmap.Width > bitmap.Height)
        {
            //Width is large, calculate height
            height = Convert.ToInt32(width * (bitmap.Height * 1.0 / bitmap.Width));
        }
        else
        {
            //height is large, calculate width
            width = Convert.ToInt32(height * (bitmap.Width * 1.0 / bitmap.Height));
        }
        Bitmap result = ResizeImage(bitmap, width, height);
    
        filename = filename.Substring(0,filename.LastIndexOf('.'))+".jpg";
        //Save the picture and specify the save format as Jpeg, which will take up less space
        result.Save(targetname,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        result.Dispose();
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
    /// <summary>  
    ///  Resize img
    /// </summary>  
    /// <param name="bmp">original Bitmap </param>  
    /// <param name="newW">new width</param>  
    /// <param name="newH">new heights</param>  
    /// <returns>Process later pictures</returns>  
    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap bmp, int newW, int newH)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(newW, newH);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
            // The quality of the interpolation algorithm
            //g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, newW, newH), new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.Dispose();
            return b;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I thought about it, if it is stored in the server, will it take up a lot of space under high concurrency? What do you recommend?

Comment: You can put these captcha images into the Redis cache and delete it after the user input is successfully validated, or you can set its expiration time, you can check this post to use redis, combined with the suggestions mentioned above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70328736/net-core-third-party-graphics-verification/70329396#70329396